# How to sum column of different file in bash scripting

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have two files:

#### file-1

```
1  2  3  4  
1  2  3  4  
1  2  3  4
```

#### file-2

```
0.5  
0.5  
0.5
```

Now I want to add column 1 of `file-2` to column 3 of `file-1`

#### Output

```
1  2  3.5  4  
1  2  3.5  4  
1  2  3.5  4
```

I've tried this, but it does not work correctly:

```
awk '{print  $1, $2, $3+file-2 }'  file-2=$1_of_file-2 file-1 > file-3
```

I know the `awk` statement is not right but I want to use something like this; can anyone help me?

Comment: you can do like `paste file1 file2 | awk '{print $1, $2, ($3 + $5), $4}' > file3`

Comment: After posting the question this idea came in my mind, Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data isn't very exciting…

```
awk 'FNR == NR { for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { line[NR,i] = $i } fields[NR] = NF }
     FNR != NR { line[FNR,3] += $1
                 pad = ""
                 for (i = 1; i <= fields[FNR]; i++) { printf "%s%s", pad, line[FNR,i]; pad = " " }
                 printf "\n"
               }' file-1 file-2
```

The first pattern matches the lines in the first file; it saves each field into the pseudo-multidimensional array `line`, and also records how many fields there are in that line.

The second pattern matches the lines in the second file; it adds the value in column one to column three of the saved data, then prints out all the fields with a space between them, and adds a newline to the end.

Given this (mildly) modified input, the script (saved in file `so-25657951.sh`) produces the output shown:

```
$ cat file-1
1 2 3 4
2 3 6 5
3 4 9 6 
$ cat  file-2
0.1
0.2
0.3
$ bash so-25657951.sh
1 2 3.1 4
2 3 6.2 5
3 4 9.3 6
$
```

Note that because this slurps the whole of the first file into memory before reading anything from the second file, the input files should not be too large (say sub-gigabyte size).  If they're bigger than that, you should probably devise an alternative strategy.

For example, there is a `getline` function (even in POSIX `awk`) which could be used to read a line from file 2 for each line in file 1, and you could then simply print the data without needing to accumulate anything:

```
awk '{ getline add < "file-2"; $3 += add; print }' file-1
```

This works reasonably cleanly for any size of file (as long as the files have the same number of lines — or, more precisely, as long as `file-2` has at least as many lines as `file-1`).

Comment: This is not my actual data, i am actually trying to translate POSCAR type file of one metal to another one. In my new file distance between atoms are same as previous one but the distance from metal surface and atom is not right, so i am trying to add the differential position of previous metal to the new one. Thanks for your solution :)

Comment: Why load the first file in memory? `awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$1;next}{$3+=a[FNR]}1' file-2 file-1` should work.

Comment: My main concern is/was that with three lines of identical input in each file, you can hide bugs in the code that having different values in each of the three lines can unmask.  That's why I changed everything so that any issues like that could be spotted more reliably.  For example, with your test data, my code could have added a half to column 3 and have saved the first line, and then simply printed the saved line as the output for each subsequent line.  The test would have passed, but the code would be useless.  It would be fairly blatant here, but such things are not always as obvious.

Comment: @jaypal: There's more than one way of solving the problem; yes, you can read the second file first, but it is sometimes easier to do the first file first (though futzing with the pseudo-multidimensional array is messy and reading `file-2` first avoids that).  In any case, the `getline` solution is better than reading the second file first — and if the input is only three lines, any complaints are academic (it really doesn't matter).

Answer (score 1):

This may work:

```
cat f1
1 2 3 4
2 3 6 5
3 4 9 6
```

```
cat  f2
0.1
0.2
0.3
```

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[NR]=$1;next} {$3+=a[FNR]}1' f2 f1
1 2 3.1 4
2 3 6.2 5
3 4 9.3 6
```

After I posted it, I do see that its the same as Jaypal posted in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have one more question, sometimes script cannot understand whether * is for mathematical operation or a wild character as in ls VAS-* . let can enforce for mathematical operation but i don't like that.  here,z1= $(($fracz1*$z_multiplier)) ; it should perform multiplication operation but it is showing, 0.5 (all the file name) 10 ; that means it is not understanding that it is a mathematical operation. how can i fix this problem? Depressing thing is i am using same command in another script and it was working fine and suddenly it is creating this problem.

Comment: Try using bracket to make sure shell understand what is variable and what is not, like this: `z1= $((${fracz1}*${z_multiplier}))` If this does not help, post it in a new question, since its not directly related to what you ask for in above.